# How to run Nx serve for app with lint errors?

Tags: angular, lint, nrwl-nx

I got an nx Angular project and I got some lint rules inside

When I run `nx run shell:lint` - I got all the errors and warnings that should be according to `.eslintrc.json` config file,

but
`nx run shell:serve` - builds and serves without any errors.

This is config for `shell` `serve` operation

```
  "serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/angular:webpack-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "shell:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "shell:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {}
  }
```

But I want to get errors from linter on serve/build, Is it any way how to do that?

I can definitely catch all of them on pre-commit hook, but still want to catch it in runtime compilation.

Answer (score 0):

In your apps `project.json` file, under the "serve" command you can add the "lint" command as a dependency.

```
"serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/react:module-federation-dev-server",
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "container:build",
        "hmr": true,
        "port": 4200
      },
      "dependsOn": ["lint"],
      "configurations": {
```

Edit: This seems to only catch existing lint error when you start the command, I haven't found a way to have the lint throw and break/log in the watch command.